# Bing channel does not appear in channels list for botframework

Tags: botframework, bing

Bing search channel is no longer available as an option in dev.botframework.com for configuration. Is there a change in process or a different way to register my bot on Bing search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still be there but seperated into `More channels` section. Or try the link `https://dev.botframework.com/bots/channels?id=<your_bot>&channelId=bing` to visit this page directly.

[image]